# DB2のTIMESTAMP_FORMATのフォーマットについて

Tags: sql, db2

DB2でYYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SSの形式でSELECTを掛けたいです。

DB上で以下のようにNUMBER型で定義されているため一度2つのカラムをCHAR型に変換し、CONCATでくっつけた後にTIME_STAMP_FORMATで'YYYY-MM-DD HH:24:MI:SS'の形式で日付型に変換しました。

```
カラムA: 20200605
カラムB: 120000
```

するとなぜか結果が'2020-06-05-12.00.00.000000'と結果が返ってきました。
私の想定では'2020-06-05 12:00:00'となると思っていました。

試しに以下のようにしてテストしてみたところ同様に'2020-01-01-00.00.00.000000'という結果になりました。
これはTIMESTAMP_FORMATの仕様でしょうか？
それならば私が求めている結果を得るにはどのようにすればよいでしょうか？

```sql
SELECT 
TIMESTAMP_FORMAT(CONCAT(CHAR(20200101),CHAR(000000)), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:24:MI:SS') 
FROM TEST_TABLE;
```

Comment: SELECT TIMESTAMP_FORMAT(CONCAT(CHAR(20200101),CHAR(000000)), 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS') FROM TEST_TABLE;またはSELECT TIMESTAMP_FORMAT(CONCAT(CHAR(20200101),' ',CHAR(000000)), 'YYYYMMDD HH24MISS') FROM TEST_TABLE;を実行したらどうなりますか？

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is what you need?

```
VALUES TIMESTAMP(TIMESTAMP_FORMAT(CONCAT(CHAR(20200101),DIGITS(DEC(CHAR(000000),6))), 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS'),0)
```

returns

```
 2020-01-01 00:00:00
```

or you could use e.g.

```
VALUES TIMESTAMP('2020-01-01'::DATE,0)
```

to get the same result

Comment: Thank you for reply but I don't need millisecond.
I need just '2020-01-01 00:00:00'.

Comment: I have edited my answer